# Fatal error while inserting data into Sqlite on Android 2.2 emulator

Tags: android, sqlite

when i am inserting data into database, i am getting the following error from Log

```
12-15 13:50:59.174: D/AndroidRuntime(15829): Shutting down VM
12-15 13:50:59.174: W/dalvikvm(15829): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at com.carettech.android.CaretTechActivity.inserting(CaretTechActivity.java:120)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at com.carettech.android.CaretTechActivity.adding(CaretTechActivity.java:107)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at com.carettech.android.CaretTechActivity$1.onClick(CaretTechActivity.java:55)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-15 13:50:59.184: E/AndroidRuntime(15829):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and the code i used to insert is:

```
SQLiteDatabase Database;
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NAME,a.getNAME());
    values.put(EMAIL, a.getEmail());
    values.put(PLACE,a.getPlace());
    Database.insert(CARET_TECH_TABLE, null, values);
```

and i tried this one also

```
String sql =   "INSERT INTO "+CARET_TECH_TABLE+" ("+NAME+","+EMAIL+","+PLACE+") "
           +"VALUES ('"+ a.getNAME() + "', '" + a.getEmail() + "', '" +a.getPlace()+"')";
    Log.v("Test Saving", sql);
    Database.execSQL(sql, null);
```

Not able to debug and find the issue... appreciate your help!

Comment: how you are getting instance of Database? check if it is null

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing you database object

```
SQLiteDatabase Database;
```

// Before you user that you must create database object 
// user your Datatabse class in which you are creating method etc

```
Database = new Database(context);
```

// Or Before you user that you must create database object

```
SQLiteDatabase Database = context.openOrCreateDatabase("my_database_name", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);


ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NAME,a.getNAME());
    values.put(EMAIL, a.getEmail());
    values.put(PLACE,a.getPlace());
    Database.insert(CARET_TECH_TABLE, null, values);
```